# Is there dry_run functionality for APN?

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, apn, dry-run

While implementing notification sending functionality for android and ios, I ran into the issue where dry run is needed.

For FCM, [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) solved the problem but the issue still remains for APN. **Is there the dry run functionality for APN?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### clevertap library solved the issue.

The Content Available option with below value initialized did the work for me.

- Key: content-available
- Value: 1

The official documentation states as below:

> Suppose you include the content-available key with a value of 1 to
> send out a silent notification to your users. In that case, it will
> not alert the user in any way (update badge count/play a sound/show a
> notification), but it will wake your app up in the background,
> allowing you to fetch new content and prepare it for the next time the
> user opens your app.

For more information, click [here](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/push-notifications-ios).

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`validate_only`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send#request-body) in FCM v1 API.

Comment: your comment holds good for FCM.